# How to instantiate a JS widget on all elements with a specific class upon their creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically built page that brings in many elements via ajax. I would like to use the [select2](https://select2.github.io/) plugin for a particular drop down, which is in a partial view and can be loaded into multiple diffrent areas of the page via ajax, specifically when a user clicks a button to add a new element on the page. I have decided to handle this by instantiating it for all instances of `select2` class.

```
    function makeSelect2(){
        $(this).select2();
    }
    $('.select2').each(makeSelect2);
    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted','.select2', makeSelect2);
```

the problem with the above code is that the `.select2()` call is generating new elements on the page, which are bubbling up and causing more calls to `makeSelect2`. Essentially, I am stuck in an infinite loop.

I found some examples online saying to use [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery), but those seem to be a few years old, and livequery hasn't been updated in over a year.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues, and solved by selecting only the `select` tags, and also adding a class to them once they where initialized, said class would serve as a flag to know whether or not to call the `select2` function:

```
function makeSelect2(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('select2Init')) return;
    $(this).addClass('select2Init').select2();
}
$('select.select2').each(makeSelect2);
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted','select.select2', makeSelect2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) event which is triggered after an ajax event is completed successfully, that is, the `success` event handler has been executed.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $('.select2').each(makeSelect2);
});
```

However it's more efficient to instantiate them in the `success` handler itself.